# Aggregate function with limit and without full table scan

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have `photo` table:

```
create table photo(
    id integer,
    ...
    user_id integer,
    created_at date
);
```

I'd like to achieve the same result as:

```
select 
    json_agg(photo), 
    created_at,
    id_user
from photo
group by created_at, id_user
order by created_at desc, id_user 
limit 5;
```

but avoiding full table scan on `photo`.

Is it possible? I was thinking of recursive CTE but I couldn't manage to construct it.

Comment: I don't get it. You want to aggragate data from whole table but without looking up this table fully?

Comment: Remember you limitting query output not table rows. PostgreSQL needs to scan whole table because values for groups may be anyware.

Comment: can you show us the execution PLAN?

Comment: @Gabriel'sMessanger the problem isnt the output. The problem is the `ORDER BY` that mean sorting and that mean full scan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have an index on `photo(id_user, created_at)`, then you can select the five rows that you want using a subquery.  Then use a join or correlated subquery to get the rest of the information:

```
select cu.created_at, cu.id_user,
       (select json_agg(p.photo)
        from photo p
        where cu.created_at = p.created_at and cu.id_user = p.id_user
       )
from (select distinct created_at, id_user
      from photo p
      order by created_at desc, id_user
      limit 5
     ) cu
order by cu.created_at desc, cu.id_user ;
```

Comment: @Radek: I think this is the most suitable way of doing that. Can you try it and show us the execution plan of this query?

Comment: There is not enough space for whole plan in comment, but indeed it does `index only scan` instead of `sequence scan`

Answer (score 1):

Not recursive, You can try with a single CTE to see if get the TOP 5 without full scan

```
WITH cte as (
  SELECT DISTINCT created_at, id_user
  FROM photo
  ORDER BY created_at DESC, id_user
  LIMIT 5
)
SELECT p.created_at, p.id_user, json_agg(p.photo)
FROM photo p
JOIN cte c
  ON p.created_at = c.created_at 
 AND p.id_user = c.id_user
GROUP BY p.created_at, p.id_user
ORDER BY p.created_at DESC, p.id_user
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is an index on `created_at` and it is possible to suppose there are at least 5 photos in the last 24 hours (or 48 or whatever) it is possible to avoid the full scan:

```
select 
    json_agg(photo), 
    created_at,
    id_user
from photo
where created_at > (select max(created_at) from photo) - interval '24 hours'
group by created_at, id_user
order by created_at desc, id_user 
limit 5;
```

The shorter the interval the shorter the scan.

Comment: What if the last created_at was a week ago? Or a year? That is a good way of restricting scan, but only if we can assume some things I believe he can not do.

Comment: @ChristianB.Almeida Yes, you are correct, some assumptions must be made. Although I guess they are reasonable. I added a workaround for the case you mention. BTW the other two answers as of now indeed do a full scan.

Comment: @ChristianB.Almeida If the table is that sparsely populated as in there are no photos in the last week then the whole question is moot.

Comment: I created a table for testing and ran all queries. Neither of them did a full scan. The fastest one was yours, but (again) with assumptions I would not do.

Comment: We can't make assumptions about photos density in time. But anyway it's nice trick :)

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Did you try Gordon answer with a composite key?